# How do I retrieve all records that are NOT in a many to many association using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Sequelize gives you the ability to define a many to many association between tables which adds some extra functionality to a Model instance.

I have a Users table and I have defined a self-association on the table like so:
`User.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'Friends', as: 'friends', foreignKey: 'userId' });`

This gives the instance of the User model a couple of extra methods like `user.getFriends()`. So far so good.

What I want to do is to get all users who aren't friends of our instance. Something like `user.getNonFriends()`. Would that be possible using Sequelize?

Comment: Hey bro, can you try to log the query generated by the getFriends method? for debugging?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution I can think of is, you could get the list of friends of the user A from the database. Using that result you can get the friends list that is not in the user's A list. Here is an example in code

```
const friends = user.getFriends();
const friendIds friends.map(friend => friend.id)
Friend.findAll({ where: {
      id: { $notIn: [...friendIds] }
     }
 })
```

Comment: Nice try @Titilope but this may lead to performance issues in the future..
Imagine if the user has 10k friends!

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi I know this will lead to performance issues, that's why I said it was a quick solution.

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi To overcome the performance you mentioned, you could run a subquery in the NOT IN operator thus eliminating the need for user.getFriends. Have a look at this answer for more information about subquery in NOT IN operation in sequelize
 https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3961#issuecomment-278193859